# Is there a way to setup manual TCP/IP configuration on MacOS only for specific networks?

Tags: macos, dhcp, tcpip

I need to have a static IP address only when I connect to the network generated by a custom device that I have. Is there a way to do this operation automatically without having to type IP, gateway and subnet every time and switching from DHCP to Manual mode every time?

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a new Location, ready-filled with the necessary data.

It's been hidden [along with most things] in Ventura - in System Settings > Network > [kebab menu] > Locations

That way, you only have one switch to flip, the rest is automatic.